# python, numpy generate bad data

Tags: python, numpy, auto-generate

I'm trying to make a writeup on different ways to deal with bad data.  right now, I'm working on Null/None/Nan.

I want convert random values in an array to Null, and then just print it out, or manipulate it in other ways.

I create the data as

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
```

And can make a random mask with

```
mask = np.random.random(size=X.shape)
mask = np.array([[True if y< .9 else False for y in x] for x in mask])
```

But I don't know how to apply that mask to the data. What I want to do is keep the value in `X` if the corresponding value in `mask` is `True`, otherwise convert it to `None`

the way I do it right now isn't pretty, I feel like a more pythonic way exists

```
i= 0
while i < len(X):
    j=0
    while j < len(X[i]):
        X[i][j] = X[i][j] if mask[i][j] else None
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
print(X)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mask = np.random.choice([False, True], size=X.shape, p=[0.9, 0.1])
X[mask] = np.nan
```

Here's a minimal `ipython` session with your dataset if you would like to see how it works

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: from sklearn import datasets
In [3]: iris = datasets.load_iris()
In [4]: X = iris.data[:6]
In [5]: X
Out[5]: 
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
       [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4]])

In [6]: mask = np.random.choice([False, True], size=X.shape, p=[0.9, 0.1])
In [7]: mask.astype(int)
Out[7]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])

In [8]: X[mask] = np.nan
In [9]: X
Out[9]: 
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [nan, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [nan, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
       [5.4, nan, 1.7, 0.4]])
```

Comment: @MohammadAthar then you probably didn't copy his code directly, or your dataset is not a numpy array.

Comment: @MohammadAthar see the edit, not sure why it doesn't work there

Comment: @MohammadAthar if you have to work with an object that doesn't support numpy style slicing (most of these answers rely on that), but does support element-wise multiplication, you could change `[False, True]` in the mask creation to `[1.0, np.nan]` and then change the assignment from `X[mask] = np.nan` to `X *= mask`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
mask = np.random.random(size=X.shape)
X[mask > .9] = None
```

---

Working example:

```
x = np.ones((5, 5))
mask = np.random.random(size=x.shape)
# array([[ 0.46578606,  0.75331373,  0.05911855,  0.85127777,  0.85549141],
#        [ 0.20080012,  0.37121033,  0.69645537,  0.76756564,  0.42591026],
#        [ 0.84719144,  0.17824992,  0.81800073,  0.26026423,  0.89056928],
#        [ 0.90355276,  0.93950118,  0.62471001,  0.17618564,  0.15952916],
#        [ 0.08325249,  0.64214048,  0.60089593,  0.94820258,  0.62338702]])
x[mask > .9] = None
# array([[  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
#        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
#        [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
#        [ nan,  nan,   1.,   1.,   1.],
#        [  1.,   1.,   1.,  nan,   1.]])
```

Comment: I did, but just get all nan when I do that

Comment: As mentioned by @Aaron on another reply, you may be misusing this code. I added a working example to my answer to illustrate.

Comment: this works.  I'll kick my code around and see what i'm doing wrong. thanks!

Comment: @MohammadAthar I believe using `np.nan` as filippo did may serve you better than `None`, as it is of `type(np.nan) -> <class 'float'>`, so it will play nicer with any mathematical calculation you want to do on the data. Numpy auto-converts in some cases (as seen in the example), but it's usually better just to write it out.

Comment: I agree with @Aaron. I chose not to edit my answer though, for authenticity and as I am not sure of OP's final goal with this code (as OP mentioned "working on Null/None/Nan", maybe as different cases).

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to write it within a single line :

```
X = [ [ xi if mi else None for xi, mi in zip(x,m) ] for x, m in zip(X, mask) ]
```